# How to call columns without using Group By clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I am new to sql, i had one  doubt

```
    select  t1.PayeeCode,t1.PayeeName,t1.PayeeIFSCCode,t1.grossAmount as ga,t2.Deduction          
      as da,(t1.grossAmount-t2.Deduction) as SubAmount from (
     (select PayeeCode,PayeeName,PayeeIFSCCode,PayeeBankAcNo,sum(PayeeAmount) as  
    grossAmount from tblPayees where AccountType='g' group by payeeCode, PayeeName,PayeeIFSCCode,PayeeBankAcNo) t1

        inner join

     (select PayeeCode,sum(PayeeAmount) as deduction from tblPayees where   
       AccountType='d' group by payeeCode) t2

 on t1.PayeeCode=t2.PayeeCode
 )
```

curent  result

```
    
PayeeCode    payeename   payeeifsccode   ga   da   subamount  type
--------------------------------------------------------------
p1              x        123         1300   1400  100         g
p1              z        34             450    550  100         g
p1              y        35            150    150  0          d
p2              z        45            150   100   50         d
```

expected result:

```
                                                                                                  
PayeeCode   payeename   payeeifsccode   ga   da   subamount  type
--------------------------------------------------------------
p1              x        123         1750    1950  200        g
p1              y         35        300     250   50        d
```

Here this is the Column 'tblPayees.PayeeName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I know here why eeror is occured but , i dont want to group by payeeName, i wnat only payeecode.How to do that? 
   help me please

Comment: in the  group by payeeCode  should it be capitalized as--  group by PayeeCode   ?  in both group by clauses?

Comment: both the group by claueses

Comment: group by PayeeCode as capitalized also no problem

Comment: @sandeep Post sample data as it is instead of the query results.

Comment: database structure u wnat?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you either need to include the column in `group by`  clause or use an aggregate in select list like `MIN`, `MAX`, etc. otherwise the database engine doesn't know what to do with it i.e. what value from the group to select.

Now are you sure you cannot group on both columns? Can you have different PayeeName for the same PayeeCode? If not, you can include it in group by:

```
select PayeeCode, PayeeName from tblPayees group by PayeeCode, PayeeName
```

If PayeeName can vary for the same PayeeCode then you need to tell the database engine which value you want to select by means of aggregate function:

```
select PayeeCode, Max(PayeeName) as PayeeName from tblPayees group by PayeeCode
```

It is even possible to concatenate the PayeeName values in a comma-separated list, but this is out of scope of this question I guess.

Comment: i had some other columns to assign (PayeeIFSCCode,PayeeBankAcNo),i know that those should be in aggregate or group,with out adding in this two,how to do that like any other option like trigger,stored procedure?

Comment: @sandeep I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe if you add more details in your question, like current results, expected results I'd be able to help.